# Запятые при союзе "значит"

Tags: запятые

Нужно ли ставить запятую после союза "значит"? В Интернете много мнений, например, на "Грамоте.ру" пишут, что нужно ставить. И как отличить "значит" в качестве вводного слова от "значит" в роли союза? Пример : "На улице пасмурно, значит будет дождь.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**На улице пасмурно, значит, будет дождь.**

Слово ЗНАЧИТ условно можно назвать союзом, так как этот союз **на границе предложений** выделяется запятой. Как структурный элемент ЗНАЧИТ может входить в двойной подчинительный союз ЕСЛИ...ЗНАЧИТ, где после него также ставится запятая: *Если наступит весна, значит, будет тепло*.

Правила

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp12212)  (п.12)

Если слово значит находится между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения, **то оно выделяется запятыми:** *Прозвенел звонок, значит, урок кончился; Не уберегли ребёнка, значит, пеняйте на самого себя.*

2) http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?id=58_220&layout=item2.

Союз. Соединяет предложения или части сложного предложения  (в том числе в составе двойного союза «если... значит» или «раз... значит»). Сближаясь по значению с вводными словами «следовательно», «таким образом», **союз «значит» отделяется запятой (реже тире) от последующей части предложения:**...в армию его не взяли, значит, будет жить.

Answer (score 1):

Отличие только в том, что союз "значит" соединяет простые предложения в составе сложного.

При этом по факту слово является вводным, но по правилу его относят к союзам, так как роль соединителя предложений важнее, чем вводность.

Поэтому выделять пунктуацией нужно в обоих случаях.

Comment: А что же  союз ЗНАЧИТ делает в БСП, то есть бессоюзном предложении? В БСП  основное средство связи - это интонация.   А в двух других сложных предложениях (ССП и СПП у нашего союза всего лишь вторые роли. Поэтому выделение запятыми определяется  именно вводностью слова ЗНАЧИТ, а вовсе не соединительными свойствами.

Comment: Ну так у него всегда есть вводные качества, если это не глагол. В "а значит" нужно смотреть, куда "а" относится. http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=1026

Comment: Вы согласно, что это БСП? А согласны, что ЗНАЧИТ в этом случае не союз, а вводное слово на границе двух предложений в БСП? А про "а" здесь вроде бы речи не было, там своя история (тоже не самая простая).

Comment: Просто показалось, что в предложении про ССП и СПП имеется ввиду связка с другим союзом... || Похоже на БСП, так как можно заменить на тире. Союз - это то, что соединяет (чем бы оно ни было). Но по факту часть речи не меняется, но добавляется новая очень важная функция, которая важнее вводности и связывает хоть и не структурно, но, главное, по смыслу предложение (что не делают запятая и тире). Поэтому учёные склонились к тому, чтобы назвать союзом. Если быть точнее, то это два в одном. Но классификация предусматривает строгое деление.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, но понимаю я вас как-то неотчетливо. Кажется, даже вообще не понимаю почти ничего.

Comment: Я тоже ваш первый комментарий почти не понял изначально))) Ладно, могу и по-простому говорить. Союзы - это любые слова, которые соединяют части. Простые союзы (и, а) относятся ко второй части и добавляют её. Но союз "значит" относится к обеим частям. Он, как знак "равно", соединяет предложение. Если убрать простые союзы, то проблем со смыслом не будет, предложение станет БСП. А если убрать "значит" - смысл может сильно теряться. Его роль важнее. Этим он похож на СПП, где убрать связующее слово - и сильно сломается смысл. То есть это союз как вводное слово в ССП. Учёные правы. Так лучше?)))